# How to use GenericMessageJacksonDeserializer with Spring Kafka and Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I wanted to know how to use GenericMessageJacksonDeserializer with spring kafka consumer factory if my kafka message is of type GenericMessage ?

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<?, GenericMessage> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    final Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
    final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<?, GenericMessage> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties);
    consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(GenericMessageJacksonDeserializer.class);
    return consumerFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer()` is for `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` object, even not for class.
2. I guess you mean `org.springframework.integration.support.json.GenericMessageJacksonDeserializer`
   Which is exactly for the `ObjectMapper` configuration. You should use `JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper()`, which is, err..., really aware of that `GenericMessageJacksonDeserializer` already.
3. When you get that `ObjectMapper`, you should inject it into the... custom `Deserializer` implementation. And already that one use for that `consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer()`. The `messagingAwareMapper` is not going work as expected with `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` because this one really need a specific type for deserialization. However we may try something like this:

   ```
   consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(new JsonDeserializer(GenericMessage.class, JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper()));
   ```

Comment: I am getting this exception, Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[34, 72, 73, 32, 49, 34]]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class' that is to contain type id  (for class org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage)
 at [Source: [B@621f8986; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Right, you have to serialize on another side using the same  ` messagingAwareMapper`

Comment: I am still getting the same exception. Here is the same code. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a955b573fd3496ed7a39923d8c21d871

Comment: Ok! Then we don't have choice unless implement custom generic deserializer. And that one already will be able to deal with the `messagingAwareMapper`. The sample is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java